# get JSlider's input and changes

Tags: java, jpanel, actionlistener, joptionpane, jslider

I need to use JSlider with getting input live, meaning that it will return an input without pressing any button. I have this piece of code for the slider:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            JSlider js = new JSlider(JSlider.VERTICAL, 0, 20, 10);
            js.setMajorTickSpacing(2);
            js.setPaintTicks(true);
            Hashtable labelTable = new Hashtable();
            labelTable.put(new Integer(js.getMinimum()), new JLabel("x0"));
            labelTable.put(new Integer((js.getMinimum() + js.getMaximum()) / 2), new JLabel("x1"));
            labelTable.put(new Integer(js.getMaximum()), new JLabel("x2"));
            js.setLabelTable(labelTable);
            js.setPaintLabels(true);
            panel.add(js);
            int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, panel, "choose size", JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);
```

Is it even possible to do so? I thought using actionListener but I didn't succeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible, using a ChangeListener, for example

```
slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        JSlider slider = (JSlider) e.getSource();
        int value = slider.getValue();
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't update while I change the slider, but only after pressing a button(JOptionPane.YES_OPTION).

Comment: Then don't use the `JOptionPane` dialog then, just embed the panel in a regular UI. The dialog is blocking until the button is clicked :)

Comment: Sorry, it is my first project, how to do that?

Comment: Just add the panel to a `JFrame` instead. I suggest going through the [Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) before going any further :)